# List all the shares on facebook made from my app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im building an app that grants you points for sharing videos or pictures on facebook.

Each time you share media you gain +1 point. 
Each time your shared media is **re-shared** you gain +1 point.

Eventually, the users with most shared videos or pictures will be ranked on a leader board with the most shared/viral at the top.

I'm aware that you can get the share count of a specific post using

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post?locale=es_LA

But for the leader board I would have to get the info of each specific post and the sort them on my end.

**Is there are way through the Facebook graph API to get all posts made from the users of my app sorted by shares?**